# Upload Very Large Files

Tags: php, html

I have referenced this site many times, but just signed up because I am stump. I have html and php files I want to use for uploading files up to 10G with. The upload works great up to 5G. Any file larger than that produces **"Warning: Undefined array key "the_file" in /downloads/recovery/var/www/html/Uploader/fileUploadScript.php"** and dies after processing about 10 minutes. I ran tests with 1G, 2G, 3G, 4G, 5G, 7G and 10G files, 7G and 10G produced warnings. The code blocks below are the two files I am using to upload files with.

Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="fileUploadScript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="Upload">Select File</label><br>
      <input type="file" name="the_file" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>
      <label for="submit">Upload File</label><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Upload">
   </form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
   $currentDirectory = getcwd();
   $uploadDirectory = "/uploads/";
      
   $errors = [];
      
   echo "Upload size: " . $_FILES['the_file']['size'] . "<br>";
   $fileName = $_FILES['the_file']['name'];
   $fileSize = $_FILES['the_file']['size'];
   $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'];
   $fileType = $_FILES['the_file']['type'];
   $uploadPath = $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName);
     
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      if ($fileSize > 112640000000) {
         $errors[] = "File exceeds maximum size (11G)";
      }
     
     if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);
     
        if ($didUpload) {
           echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
        } else {
           echo "An error occurred. Please contact the administrator.";
        }
     } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
           echo $error . "<br>" . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
     }
     
  }
?>
```

Comment: Have you changed your PHP settings `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to allow for this? Generally if an uploaded file exceeds that, it won't show up in the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: Docs reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: I would look into something like blueimp that can upload large files in chunks. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Make sure your server itself, along with any intermediaries, such as firewalls, supports large files, too.

Comment: Rylee - Thank you for the suggetions, yes I have updated all of the size settings for PHP

Chris - I am running on a local server, no firewalls, thank you.

Comment: Rylee - Thank you for the suggetions, yes I have updated all of the size settings for PHP. I would really like to stick with straight PHP as I have enough troubles trying to keep up with it. Just rebuilt my server and when I reinstalled PHP8 was installed and more of my code quite working all together. I ended up installing 7.4 to get everything working again.
Chris - I am running on a local server, no firewalls, thank you.

Comment: It seems as though there is an issue between the HTML code and the PHP code. If I upload a 5G file I will see the temp file in the upload folder as soon as I hit the sunmot button. If I rty to upload a 7G there is no temp file beeing generated after i hit submit.